# Getting value of std::list<>::iterator to pointer?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

How can i loop thru a stl::List and store the value of one of the objects for use later in the function?

```
Particle *closestParticle;
for(list<Particle>::iterator p1 = mParticles.begin(); p1 != mParticles.end(); ++p1 )
     {
      // Extra stuff removed
            closestParticle = p1; // fails to compile (edit from comments)
     }
```

Comment: Are you trying to say this code doesn't compile? `// fails` usually indicates you mean a run-time error.

Comment: @rlbond: I agree that `// fails to compile` would be better (although in this example I assumed that the compiler error wasn't an unwanted side-effect of pasting the code), but I'd disagree that `// fails` _"usually implies run-time error"_.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Either

```
Particle *closestParticle;
for(list<Particle>::iterator it=mParticles.begin(); it!=mParticles.end(); ++it)
    {
      // Extra stuff removed
            closestParticle = &*it;
    }
```

or

```
list<Particle>::iterator closestParticle;
for(list<Particle>::iterator it=mParticles.begin(); it!=mParticles.end(); ++it )
    {
      // Extra stuff removed
            closestParticle = it;
    }
```

or

```
inline list<Particle>::iterator findClosestParticle(list<Particle>& pl)
{
    for(list<Particle>::iterator it=pl.begin(); it!=pl.end(); ++it )
        {
          // Extra stuff removed
               return it;
        }
    return pl.end();
}
```

or

```
template< typename It > 
inline It findClosestParticle(It begin, It end)
{
    while(begin != end )
        {
          // Extra stuff removed
               return begin;
          ++begin;
        }
    return end;
}
```

These are sorted in increasing personal preference. `:)`

Comment: Scrolling down that was actually an enjoyable experience. +1

Comment: closestParticle = &*it // Did the trick!

Could you make what it's doing more verbose, i'm reading it as:
Go to the address of the pointer to the iterator 'it'?

Comment: Nice catch. I'd personally pick #2 as my flavor of choice. And I'm a little confused with #3 and #4. It seems like you're returning prematurely.

Comment: @Onedayitwillmake: `*it` __derferences__ the iterator and returns a __reference__ to the object. The `&` then takes the __address__ of that object. Does this explain it well enough or should one of us go into more detail?

Comment: @rlbond: I was presuming that `// Extra stuff removed` would be some conditional statement finding the best. Now that I think about it, the algorithm probably needs to traverse __all__ objects in the sequence, so premature return wouldn't bring anything.

Comment: @sbi

That does explain, but to be sure more detail is ALWAYS appreciated!
-

Comment: @Johannes: I have no idea what you're trying to tell with hinting at `rbegin()`. Knowing you I assume it's probably a great insight, but it went right over me head. `:(` I'm afraid you're presuming I thought about something you considered, and when I understand the hint I'll have to tell you that I utterly failed to think about it...

Comment: @sbi i wanted to say that using `rbegin` and `rend` will do the equivalent to his loop (assuming the commentar expands to nothing). I.e it will exit at the last item matching, not the first. Nothing really important tho.

Answer (score 1):

For a `list`, the only way to invalidate an iterator is to `erase` it. So I suspect you're calling `list.erase(p1)` at some point in the loop. You need to make a copy of the iterator, move `p1` back one, and then erase the copy.

EDIT: Oh wait, did you mean it doesn't **compile**? If so, see @sbi's answer. But you really need to word your question in a good way. What is your compile error? Or does it fail at run-time? In this case, however, I believe you mean a compile error.

Comment: I'm not sure you answered to the right question. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I meant compiler error, my mistake I was unaware of the conventions :)
-

This one did the trick:
closestParticle = &*it;

// So it's saying? 
// Go to the address of the the pointer at it?