# Pointer or reference to std::list of Eigen3 vector

Tags: c++, list, std, eigen

I'm using Eigen3 2-dimensional vector as 2D point for opengl drawing:

```
typedef Eigen::Vector2d Vec2D;
```

Then I have a `std::list` with vector and I'm iterating it in this way:

```
std::list<Vec2D>::const_iterator it;
for(it=points.begin(); it!=points.end(); ++it) {
    Vec2D p = *it;
    ... // something for draw (p.x(), p.y())
}
```

but in this way the variable `p` contains a copy, right?
Now.. I don't want to have unnecessary copies so I tried with pointers:

```
std::list<Vec2D>::const_iterator it;
for(it=points.begin(); it!=points.end(); ++it) {
    Vec2D *p = &((Vec2D)*it);
    ... // something for draw (p->x(), p->y())
}
```

I've found the strange syntax &*it [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2754656/433685) and it works even if I had to use the cast (don't know why but it didn't compile otherway).

But I'd like to use a reference instead of a pointer:

```
std::list<Vec2D>::const_iterator it;
for(it=points.begin(); it!=points.end(); ++it) {
    Vec2D &p = ???
    ... // something for draw (p->x(), p->y())
}
```

But I'm stuck on some compiling error like

```
invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Vec2D&' from a temporary of type 'Vec2D'
```

or something else that I can't understand..

Comment: did you try `const Vec2D &p = *it;`?

Comment: OMG. But are you changing a reference?

Comment: no I'm not changing it I'm only reading x() and y()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually show us what you tried. Judging by the error message, it looks like you did

```
    Vec2D &p = ((Vec2D)*it);
```

The typecast `(Vec2D)` removes the reference-ness of the expression `*it`. In official terminology, it becomes an rvalue.

The solution is simple.

```
    Vec2D &p = *it; // no cast.
```

A non-const reference must bind to an lvalue, something that can appear on the left-hand side of `=`, because the reference may be used in such a way. But

```
(Vec2D) *it = ...; // Can't assign the result of a cast expression.
```

Just for the sake of completeness, C++ does allow you to assign the result of a cast *to reference type*.

```
(Vec2D &) *it = ...; // Cast to ref type produces an lvalue.
```

Comment: I think `const Vec2D` would be required as it is `const_iterator`. Not sure though?

Comment: it get: `invalid initialization of reference of type 'Vec2D&' from expression of type 'const Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>'`

Comment: @nkint Yeah, just use `const` as appropriate, whether you want to modify it or not. The iterator should agree with the reference, of course.

Comment: @nkint If this answered your question, please check it. If you found it insightful, please upvote. The question will be highlighted on the main page until *someone* upvotes some answer here.

Comment: If so, `const Vec2D *p = it;` would also do?

Comment: @Immueggpain That would require the `&*` idiom, which converts any iterator to a pointer. `const Vec2D *p = &* it;` He discusses this in the question.

Comment: complete answer, and the right one (a parte from `const`)! anyway, can you link some documentation for understand deeper also the last part of the answer when you're talking about rvalue and lvalue and what is happening behind the hood then i type `=` ? : )